# ArcGIS Server geoprocessing service examples for shapefile data export

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-server, export, geoprocessing-service

I have a web application client built using ArcGIS Server Manager which is currently showing a single map composed by three data layers. The map data are provided as a map service by my ArcGIS Server 10.1 instance.

My task is to provide the map's users a way to download the full map locally as a shapefile (e.g: zipped) via her/his web browser.

I was hinted to read [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/GP_Service_example_Data_on_demand/00930000003v000000/) and to build a geoprocessing service to accomplish the task. I decided to write a specific toolbox myself using Python, then publish it as a geoprocessing service on my ArcGIS Server instance and finally include it into my web application.

Can you point me towards any third-party (meaning: non-ESRI) code sample to start me up?

I can find no examples other than the ones in ESRI's support website!

Comment: I dont see the code for it but the edcommunity has a jpg export application.

Comment: If you're using Esri software, why are you re-inventing/writing your own tool? This task is well documented here http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Clip_and_ship/005700000073000000/ . If you absolutely need to you can save the Extract Data tool and hack it up.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @BradNesom, can you please give me the URL/thread of this app?

Comment: I have accomplished this using python. Fork the code and make your mods. Please checkin any useful mods. You can fork here:
https://github.com/hcervantes/shpExport.git

Comment: While your code base is obviously too long to just post in your answer, could you please give a more detailed explanation of how you went about accomplishing this task using the code that you are linking too? Especially since you are going about this in a different manner from what the poster was requesting. That would be helpful to other users who would want to determine if your solution works for them without having to dig into your repository.

Answer (score 1):

The [edcommunity](http://edcommunity.esri.com/) has a sample app, but no downloadable code. As per KHibma the [clip and ship](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Clip_and_ship/005700000073000000/) will probably work.
If you aren't clipping the [Edcommunity Sketch-A-Map](http://edcommunity.esri.com/maps/sketchAMap2/index.html) app uses a draw widget to export.

Answer (score 0):

When we needed this, we just pregenerated a zip file for each layer, and had a link in a custom legend which allowed you to download the data, and just housed the zip files on the site. Not 'slick and automatic', but it gives a way for the user to download the data if they want.

Comment: What if the data is dynamic being hosted on the server. This approach will not work which is why the OP is asking his for an answer to his approach